# nginx proxy_pass is setting port in response

Tags: nginx, proxy, http-headers, reverse-proxy

I have an Nginx config similar to:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name api.mysite.dev;

    location / {

        proxy_set_header Host "api.mysite.dev";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass  $scheme://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }

}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name mysite.dev www.mysite.dev;

    # Forward all /api/ requests ti api.mysite.dev
    # sadly need to keep this around for backwards compatibility
    location /api/ {
        proxy_set_header Host "api.mysite.dev";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass $scheme://127.0.0.1:8001/;

    }
    # The proxy_pass here ends up putting the port (8002) in the response URL.
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host "www.mysite.dev";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass  $scheme://127.0.0.1:8002;
    }
}
```

So, as said in the comment, when I request www.mysite.dev, my browser is forwarded to www.mysite.dev:8002.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set the following options:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
```

This is a sample that works:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443;
        server_name api.mysite.dev;

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001/;
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Host "api.mysite.dev";
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't solve the problem. Some more info:
The browser is getting redirected to whatever is in the Host header. So if I set that to 'www', and request www.mysite.dev/some/resource, the browser gets sent to www:8002/some/resource.

Comment: I just noticed you are missing this header which I always use for reverse proxies proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

Comment: So, this was *mostly* correct, so I edited your answer. Adding "proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;" is what fixed it for me in the end.